# How to use a value in a JSON file within an if statement

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to create an if statement based on the value from an API I'm using. This API contains a status code value, `"status"`. if this is 404 (or others) I want to return an error, else carry on.

An example of the JSON:

```
{
  "data": {
    "test_index": {
      "test_a": [...], // 429 items
      "test_b": [...]  // 182 items
      }
  },
  "status": 200
}
```

When running the code below:

```
import json
import urllib.request as ur

API = ur.urlopen('https://example.com')
data = json.loads(API.read())

if data['status'][0] == 404:
    print("404")
else:
    print("Not 404")
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Which is referring to line 7, the if statement.

How do I convert this JSON value to something I can work with?

Comment: `data['status']` is an integer, `200` in your example, so what was expected from `data['status'][0]`?

Comment: if you check `type(data['status'])` which comes out be integer operator `[]` (subscript) is not defined for integer, it is defined for list, string, dict in the fundamental types.

Comment: `data` is an ordinary Python data structure, not JSON. (You decoded the JSON response with `json.loads` in order to *define* `data`; you can just take a look at the entire `dict` to see what it looks like.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data['status']` is an integer, and you cannot subscript an integer with an index, like you do for a list, Change your code as follows.

```
if data['status'] == 404:
    print("404")
else:
    print("Not 404")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks like I need to brush up on when and where to index. As a side note, if the URL does have a 404 status code, urllib cannot handle it and gives HTTPError: Not Found.  I ended up using requests.get().

Comment: Great, glad that I am of help!